# Работает один с прогресс бар с 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет у меня есть прогресс бар который активируется при скролле но идущие после него прогресс бары не работают.Я пробовал создать каждому прогресс бару отдельную функцию типа move2 move3 и вызывать в

```
if ((scrollTop + windowHeight) >= offsetTop) {
    move(95);
    $(document).off('scroll')
  }
```

Но это не сработало.Хотелось бы узнать как это сделать одной функцие чтобы вызывать ее с параметром процентов заполненности.

```
<div class="SkillsMain">
                <div class="Skills">
                    <p class="Exp-BigText">Skills</p>
                    <p class="Skills-text">C++ development</p>
                    <div class="Progress" id="Progress1" onscroll="move(95)">
                        <div class="bar" id="bar1">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="Skills-text">.Net</p>
                    <div class="Progress" id="Progress2" onscroll="move2(75)">
                        <div class="bar" id="bar2">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="Skills-text">HTML5</p>
                    <div class="Progress" id="Progress3" onscroll="move(85)">
                        <div class="bar" id="bar3" >

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="Skills-text">jQuery</p>
                    <div class="Progress" id="Progress4" onscroll="move(90)">
                        <div class="bar" id="bar4">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="Skills-text">Angular</p>
                    <div class="Progress" id="Progress5" onscroll="move(70)">
                        <div class="bar" id="bar5">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
Progress
    position: relative
    width: 490px
    height: 20px
    background-color: $white
.bar
    position: absolute
    width: 1%
    height: 100%
    background-color: $green
    &::after
        display: block
        content: ""
        position: absolute
        height: 10px
        width: 10px
        background: #353535
        border-left: 2px solid $very-dark
        border-top: 2px solid $very-dark
        bottom: 25px
        right: 1px
        transform: rotate(-135deg)
```

JS

```
    var offsetTop = $('#Progress').offset().top,
  windowHeight = $(window).height();

function move(max_width,id_elem) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id_elem);
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= max_width) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }


}
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

  if ((scrollTop + windowHeight) >= offsetTop) {
    move(95,'bar1');
    move(75,'bar2');
    move(85,'bar3');
    move(90,'bar4');
    move(70,'bar5');
    $(document).off('scroll')
  }

})
```

Comment: у вас повторяющиеся `id`, что недопустимо ! Вот и работает первый который выберется, переделайте стили прогресов под `css` классы, дайте им уникальные `id` и активируйте уже по `id` нужный вам прогрес

Comment: Если задавать каждому отдельный id то делать отдельную функцию   под каждый прогрессбар?

Comment: зачем ? можно ж сделать 1ну функу в которую например передавать ид прогреса, который надо активировать

Comment: Спасибо все заработало,обновил код с правильным ответом.